# Linq EntityState Problem

Tags: c#, linq

Hello How can I change `EntityState` from `NotTracked` to `Modified` of my `CurrentEntity`.
I mean I do modify my `CurrentyEntity` but the `EntityState` shows `NotTracked` where it should be `Modified`. What could be reason behind this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a change to a disconnected entity and want it to be change tracked, you can use the .Attach(..) method on your datacontext, ie:

```
context.Products.Attach(product, true);
```

You can read more about Linq to Sql and disconnected entities on MSDN:

[Data Retrieval and CRUD Operations in N-Tier Applications (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546187.aspx)